# How to look up the ENUM type given a string?

Tags: c++, enums, c-str

I have an enum class like this:

```
class ContentTypeEnum {

 public:

  // it might have more types
  enum Code { TEXT, XML, APPLICATION_JSON};

  static const char* to_c_str(unsigned);

};
```

I was using it like this in my code as of now.

```
ContentTypeEnum::APPLICATION_JSON
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now I have a string given so I need to use that string and then find the actual ENUM type by iterating it my above enum.

Below is my code:

```
cout<<"Given String: " << data_args->pp_args->ter_strings[0].c_str() << endl;
const char* test_str = data_args->pp_args->ter_strings[0].c_str();
```

Now if `test_str` is `xml` or `XML`, then I need to set it like this:

```
TestClass::SetContentType(ContentTypeEnum::XML)
```

But if `test_str` is `application_json` or `APPLICATION_JSON`, then I need to set it like this:

```
TestClass::SetContentType(ContentTypeEnum::APPLICATION_JSON)
```

And similarly for others as well. Below is my full code:

```
cout<<"Given String: " << data_args->pp_args->ter_strings[0].c_str() << endl;
char* test_str = data_args->pp_args->ter_strings[0].c_str();

// look up the exact ContentType from the enum using test_str string
// and then set it to below method.
TestClass::SetContentType(set_it_here_basis_on_string_test_str)
```

If somebody is passing any unknown string which is not there in my enum, then it should use by default as `TestClass::SetContentType(ContentTypeEnum::APPLICATION_JSON)`

What is the right way to lookup the exact enum type given a string?

Comment: There's no built in facility, but it's straightforward to write your own function that takes a string, compares it to hardcoded literals, and returns an enumeration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest writing a function that returns the `enum` given a string.

```
Code getCode(std::string const& s)
{
   static std::map<std::string, Code> theMap{{"TEXT", TEXT},
                                             {"XML", XML}
                                             {"APPLICATION_JSON", APPLICATION_JSON}};

   std::map<std::string, Code>::iterator it = theMap.find(s);
   if ( it != theMap.end() )
   {     
      return it->second;
   }
   return APPLICATION_JSON;
}
```

Comment: I'd use `const` and `find`, and be more explicit about the default of `APPLICATION_JSON`.

Comment: @MooingDuck - I'd probably toss an exception or otherwise let the caller know a match wasn't found and let the caller deal with what the default should be.  I'd probably also convert the incoming string to upper case to make a case-insensitive match.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: OP said "If somebody is passing any unknown string which is not there in my enum, then it should use by default as TestClass::SetContentType(ContentTypeEnum::APPLICATION_JSON)", so I followed that.  An exception is probably not the right idea for validating input, but maybe a `bool try_get_code(std::string const&, Code&)` wouldn't be amis.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Do we need to have `theMap` which will have all the ENUM mapping to a String? Can we not iterate the ENUM basis on the string passed and then return the ENUM type if found otherwise return APPLICATION_JSON? In general what is the advantage of using theMap here?

Comment: With this way, If I am adding another ENUM Type, then I need to update my theMap as well? Right?

Comment: @david, the advantage of using the map is less code. It might also result in faster lookup but I won't vouch for that without hard data.

Comment: @david, right. If you add more tokens to the `enum`, you'll have to update the map.

Comment: @RSahu got it. Also, how to deal with lowercase string being passed, like if somebody is passing lowercase `xml` instead of `XML`. Will it still work?

Comment: @MooingDuck - True, but I don't like burying logic decisions in a lookup method.  "Tell me what you found, not what you think I should do."  Just a personal opinion.  I should have made that more clear.

Comment: @david: The core of the issue is the exe doesn't have the names of the enumerations, period.  So to compare the input with names, you have to _add_ the names to the exe, and store them somewhere.  Thus, we make a map.  You can use `stricmp` or some other case-insensitive string comparison for those cases.

Comment: @MooingDuck understood now. I think we also need to make this case-insensitive match as well right? Bcoz anyone can pass lowercase incoming string?

Comment: If you want a case-insensitive comparison, then yes.  Do a case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: Is there any built in function to make `const& s` to upper case. Sorry asking silly question, I am coming from Java background so not sure on this.

Comment: looks like this will work `strupr(s)`. Going to try out.